# how to combine the multiple routes to single route in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

how can i minimize the routes to a particular controller.

```
Route::get('privacypolicy', 'PrivacyPolicyController@index');
Route::get('privacypolicy1', 'PrivacyPolicyController@all');
Route::get('privacypolicy/{version_no}','PrivacyPolicyController@show');
Route::get('phno/{phno},{app_type}', 'PrivacyPolicyController@check');
```

i am trying the below code but it does not work.

```
Route::controllers([
'privacypolicy' => 'PrivacyPolicyController@index',
'privacypolicy1' =>'PrivacyPolicyController@all',
'privacypolicy/{version_no}' => 'PrivacyPolicyController@show',
'phno/{phno},{app_type}' => 'PrivacyPolicyController@check',
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can us 
Route::controller('privacypolicy', 'PrivacyPolicyController');

and controller function like this: 
 public function anyIndex(){//code }

public function anyShow($version_no){//code}

Answer (score 0):

Implicit controller needs the route method name to start with the HTTP verb.
Your case cannot apply, as the route should start with the same base URI

```
Route::controller('privacypolicy','PrivacyPolicyController');

<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class PrivacyPolicyControllerextends Controller
{
    /**
     * Responds to requests to GET /privacypolicy
     */
    public function getIndex()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Responds to requests to GET /privacypolicy/show/1
     */
    public function getShow($id)
    {
        //
    }

}
```